# Div hidden to visible with timeout

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this image hidden and after 5 seconds it gets visible, but I also want it to go in a loop so after 5 seconds it goes hidden and then visible again.

This is what I have:

```js
//Shows after interval
function show() {
  document.getElementById("igpng").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("show()", 5000); // after 5 secs
```

```html
<div id='igpng' style="visibility:hidden; margin:0 auto;  height: 100px; max-width: 400px">
<img src="img/soon.png" alt="" style="max-width:100%;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `setTimeout` which runs once, use `setInterval`. Then in your function just check if the image is visible and if so hide it (and vice-versa)

```js
//Shows after interval
function toggle() {
  document.getElementById("igpng").style.visibility = (document.getElementById("igpng").style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
setInterval(toggle, 5000); // after 5 secs
```

```html
<div id='igpng' style="visibility:hidden; margin:0 auto;  height: 100px; max-width: 400px">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" alt="" style="max-width:100%;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what i was looking for